# Unicode text not properly sent/received over network

Tags: java, unicode

I am working on socket programming now, and I want to send unicode characters over network. But the characters are not displayed properly.

**The problem is that the charachers are displayed properly while running from IntelliJ IDEA IDE. But when I deploy JAR or run via command line, "???" is displayed instead of the unicode characters.**

I am using Windows 10 64 bit.

Sample text: "गूड "

Source code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("InfiniteLoopStatement")
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        final TextArea receivedTextArea = new TextArea();
        final TextArea sendTextArea = new TextArea();
        sendTextArea.setPromptText("Enter message to send.");

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(receivedTextArea, sendTextArea);

        receivedTextArea.setEditable(false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                    while (true) {
                        receivedTextArea.setText(in.nextLine());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            final PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            sendTextArea.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        out.println(sendTextArea.getText().trim());
                        sendTextArea.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Mayber IntelIJ specifies the encoding to use as default encoding. Try specifying the correct charset, e.g.: `new Scanner(socket.getInputStream(), "utf-8")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `"UTF-8"` literally everywhere(streams, byte-string conversion, etc) did the job.